# (Pseudo) Random number generation in Python without using modules and clock

Tags: python, random

I'm using Python for a competition in which I am creating a bot to play a game. The problem is, it does not have anything of c support installed, so I do not have access to the `random`, `numpy`, and `scipy` modules.

I will have roughly 400mb ram available, and I am looking for a way to produce uniform random numbers between 0 and 1 for simulation purposes during the game.

Note that I have used the clock time before to generate a single number, but the issue is that I will need loads of numbers without the clock changing much, which would result in constantly the same number. In fact, I am limited to a maximum of 1 second for, say, 100k numbers.

I'm considering loading in data, but the problem would then be that the bot would always use the same numbers. Then again, the circumstances for which I need to use the numbers vary slightly.

Using Python 2.7, hoping people have some suggestions.

Comment: Really? The core standard library module `random` is not available?

Comment: @kroolik I believe so.

Comment: Take a look at [linear congruential generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). The algorithm is pretty simple, and the results aren't bad if it's not for cryptography or high-stakes gambling.

Comment: What about the `uuid` module?

Comment: @kroolik - `uuid.uuid4()` uses `os.urandom()` if available, otherwise the `random` module.

Comment: @RyanP it also uses C modules if available before resorting to `os.urandom()` / `random`. It's worth checking whether it's working at all.

Comment: None of which is available to the OP. ;) I skipped the C part since that was already noted as not being an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) implementation. I found [this one](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578056-mersenne-twister/), which is modeled after the pseudocode on Wikipedia.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Based on the pseudocode in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister. Generates uniformly distributed 32-bit integers in the range [0, 232 − 1] with the MT19937 algorithm

Yaşar Arabacı <yasar11732 et gmail nokta com>
"""
# Create a length 624 list to store the state of the generator
MT = [0 for i in xrange(624)]
index = 0

# To get last 32 bits
bitmask_1 = (2 ** 32) - 1

# To get 32. bit
bitmask_2 = 2 ** 31

# To get last 31 bits
bitmask_3 = (2 ** 31) - 1

def initialize_generator(seed):
    "Initialize the generator from a seed"
    global MT
    global bitmask_1
    MT[0] = seed
    for i in xrange(1,624):
        MT[i] = ((1812433253 * MT[i-1]) ^ ((MT[i-1] >> 30) + i)) & bitmask_1


def extract_number():
    """
    Extract a tempered pseudorandom number based on the index-th value,
    calling generate_numbers() every 624 numbers
    """
    global index
    global MT
    if index == 0:
        generate_numbers()
    y = MT[index]
    y ^= y >> 11
    y ^= (y << 7) & 2636928640
    y ^= (y << 15) & 4022730752
    y ^= y >> 18

    index = (index + 1) % 624
    return y

def generate_numbers():
    "Generate an array of 624 untempered numbers"
    global MT
    for i in xrange(624):
        y = (MT[i] & bitmask_2) + (MT[(i + 1 ) % 624] & bitmask_3)
        MT[i] = MT[(i + 397) % 624] ^ (y >> 1)
        if y % 2 != 0:
            MT[i] ^= 2567483615

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from datetime import datetime
    now = datetime.now()
    initialize_generator(now.microsecond)
    for i in xrange(100):
        "Print 100 random numbers as an example"
        print extract_number()
```

Comment: Although this generates only integers, not floats from [0..1].

Comment: It is actually okay to generate integers.

Comment: @delnan - Easily remedied by dividing the resulting numbers by the maximum value (2^32 - 1).

Comment: If I understand it correctly I do not need to change the 624 value, just repeatedly call extract number?

Comment: No, you do not need to. The algorithm just generates 624 values at a time; you can use however many you need to. 624 is just the point at which it generates new numbers (via `generate_numbers()`).

Comment: Is it a specifically useful number, that 624 in terms of randomness or  something?

Comment: @PascalvKooten it's part of the algorithm's design.  Play with PRNG parameterization at your own peril!

Comment: Yeah, I would avoid playing with that number. But the worst that would happen is you could end up losing some of the pseudorandomness. If you're worried about performance: I tested the example with 100k numbers (and removed the print statement).... on my laptop (Core i3) it took a total of 0.371 seconds.

Comment: Also tested it on a Raspberry Pi (equivalent to a Pentium II), which took 14.631 seconds. But, comparatively, using `/dev/urandom` on the RPi as suggested by @kroolik takes far longer: I'd put a number here, but it hasn't finished generating 100k numbers yet. ;) It's well over a minute so far.

Comment: I think I will be able to do 5 simulations per turn with MT. I'm thinking it might be enough! The other methods do not work...

Comment: @RyanP, if you were using the method proposed by me, you should increase the number of bytes read to lower the amount of syscalls made. Also, a number taken from `/dev/urandom` is usually an entry point for a seed to a RNG algorithm.

Comment: @kroolik I figured as much, I just wanted a quick and easy comparison to show how incredibly slow the RPi is. ;) Since the OP doesn't have access to `/dev/urandom` anyway, the PRNG can just be seeded by microsecond time, as in the example. Like the good old days of QBasic.

Comment: @RyanP, another try could be the `uuid` module, but I'm not sure whether it relies on `urandom`.

Comment: I basically load a dictionary with over a million more common entries. I'll lower the accuracy of the simulations from 1000 to 100 reps and I should be good to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, the *random* module contains the class Wichman-Hill generator written in pure python (no C required):

```
>>> import random
>>> rng = random.WichmannHill(8675309)
>>> rng.random()
0.06246664612856567
>>> rng.random()
0.3049888099198217
```

Here's the cleaned-up source code:

```
class WichmannHill(Random):

    def seed(self, a=None):
        a, x = divmod(a, 30268)
        a, y = divmod(a, 30306)
        a, z = divmod(a, 30322)
        self._seed = int(x)+1, int(y)+1, int(z)+1

    def random(self):
        """Get the next random number in the range [0.0, 1.0)."""
        x, y, z = self._seed
        x = (171 * x) % 30269
        y = (172 * y) % 30307
        z = (170 * z) % 30323
        self._seed = x, y, z
        return (x/30269.0 + y/30307.0 + z/30323.0) % 1.0
```

Comment: This is a lot faster than the MT implementation. I will see if it works!

Comment: Unfortunately: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/urandom'`.

Answer (score 1):

If the script is ran on linux, try using `/dev/urandom`:

```
with open('/dev/urandom', 'rb') as f:
    random_int = reduce(lambda acc, x: (acc << 8) | x, map(ord, f.read(4)), 0)
```

- `f.read(4)` reads 4 bytes of entrophy
- `map(ord, f.read(4))` - converts byte-strings into numbers
- `reduce(lambda ..., map(...), 0)` - converts the list of numbers into an integer

Comment: So, the error I get when trying to use the `random` library is: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/urandom'`. Most likely this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maths is your best answer: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

X(n+1) = (aX(n)+c) mod m

```
x2 = (a*x1+c)%m
```

Comment: But take great care in choosing the parameters (a, c, m). Even careful selection can lead to poor quality, and thoughtless selection can yield generators with really really short periods. The Wikipedia article lists conditions for good canidates; it also lists values used by real world implementations. Some of those are poor, but none are catastrophically AFAIK.

Comment: @delnan With such limited resources, it's the most minimalistic though.

Comment: Performance and memory use is independent of these concerns. For any state size, there are parameters that give a decent PRNG and parameters that only spit out the same half 5 numbers again and again. You want to avoid the latter, as they simply give horrible quality numbers while costing exactly the same as if you had selected better parameters.

Comment: @delnan Any advice on those parameters? What do you need to know?

Comment: @PascalvKooten As I said, Wikipedia has the details (in the "Period length" section).